# Navigation bar with shadow & corner radius

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I would like to add corner radius & shadow on my navigation controller. 
I know how to do separately, but when I try to put both at the same time, only one is applied. I tried with CALayer, without success.

**An Image to illustrated what I want**

[image]

Comment: Please show your code. Someone may be able to help you.

Comment: I guess your problem is that if you set corner radius, then you have to mask to bounds because you want a rounded shadow; but actually masking to bounds will cut the shadow.

Comment: I have no code, what you see, that's what I want to do. And yes it's exactly that @Rico Crescenzio

Comment: @LoïcMazuc We understand your concern but SO is not like that. You will have to show your effort what you made to accomplish this. Your question is like copy paste the answer without any effort. **Rico** is asking for the same.

Comment: Please have a look at few asking rules in [SO help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Checkout the Asking section.

Comment: Also in your question you mentioned `I tried with CALayer` please show what you did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the code,

```
    // 1. Enable prefersLargeTitles and title
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    self.title = "Title"

    // 2. Add left, right bar buttons
    let leftBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Edit", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(item))
    let rtBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(item))

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rtBtn
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBtn

    //3. Change default navbar to blank UI
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.orange

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    //4. Add shadow and cirner radius to navbar
    let shadowView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -20,
                                       width: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds.width)!,
                                       height: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds.height)! + 20))
    shadowView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.insertSubview(shadowView, at: 1)

    let shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shadowLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: shadowView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft , .bottomRight , .topLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).cgPath

    shadowLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

    shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    shadowLayer.shadowPath = shadowLayer.path
    shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2.0, height: 2.0)
    shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
    shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 2

    shadowView.layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer, at: 0)
```

**Output:**

[image]

### **Edit**

You can get height dynamically using

`self.navigationController?.view.safeAreaInsets.top`

**it will return 44 for iPhone X and 20 for iPhone 8**

**Code**

```
var offset : CGFloat = (self.navigationController?.view.safeAreaInsets.top ?? 20)

let shadowView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -offset,
                                   width: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds.width)!,
                                   height: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds.height)! + offset))
```

**Output iPhoneX**

[image]

Comment: Can we use safe area layout . top instead of static value, which might be better what do you think about it ? like `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide`

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Safe area layout does not covers statusbar background, so it looked weird, if I didn't got your point then please try and update my answer for better coding 

Comment: I have updated your answer with method I have suggested to you. Please verify. You are free to update your own answer if you don't like my way of format    :) Good day

Comment: How to remove appended shadowView on viewwilldisappear ?

Answer (score 2):

Best Way is add this extension in your class add extension at the end of your class and Add shadow as well corner radius to any view as well to navigation controller :)

**image shows the `Xcode` view**

[image]

**Output of navigation controller**

[image]

```
extension UIView {


@IBInspectable
var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
    get {
        return layer.cornerRadius
    }
    set {
        layer.cornerRadius = newValue
    }
}

@IBInspectable
var borderWidth: CGFloat {
    get {
        return layer.borderWidth
    }
    set {
        layer.borderWidth = newValue
    }
}

@IBInspectable
var borderColor: UIColor? {
    get {
        if let color = layer.borderColor {
            return UIColor(cgColor: color)
        }
        return nil
    }
    set {
        if let color = newValue {
            layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
        } else {
            layer.borderColor = nil
        }
    }
}

@IBInspectable
var shadowRadius: CGFloat {
    get {
        return layer.shadowRadius
    }
    set {
        layer.shadowRadius = newValue
    }
}

@IBInspectable
var shadowOpacity: Float {
    get {
        return layer.shadowOpacity
    }
    set {
        layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
    }
}

@IBInspectable
var shadowOffset: CGSize {
    get {
        return layer.shadowOffset
    }
    set {
        layer.shadowOffset = newValue
    }
}

@IBInspectable
var shadowColor: UIColor? {
    get {
        if let color = layer.shadowColor {
            return UIColor(cgColor: color)
        }
        return nil
    }
    set {
        if let color = newValue {
            layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
        } else {
            layer.shadowColor = nil
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: i didn't get your question kindly explain

Comment: I mean how to use this code that you added in answer? If you tried that code then what is the output (take screen shot and add image).

Comment: Thanks you for reply, I tried but it's doesn't work :(

Comment: now you can use this way i added the out put you can see it :)

Comment: Thanks, I will see which solution is best for me  ! @AliXhah

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue use custom UIView. See the following code and output as you expected, I hope this helps you.

[image]

Using `cornerRadius` and `maskedCorners` to you can set specific corner radius.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        navigationView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        navigationView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner ,  .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
        navigationView.addShadow(shadowColor: UIColor.gray.cgColor, shadowOffset: CGSize(width: 1, height: 2), shadowOpacity: 0.5, shadowRadius: 20)
    }
```

**Add Following extension**

```
extension UIView {

    @IBInspectable var shadow: Bool {
        get {
            return layer.shadowOpacity > 0.0
        }
        set {
            if newValue == true {
                self.addShadow()
            }
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return self.layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = newValue

            // Don't touch the masksToBound property if a shadow is needed in addition to the cornerRadius
            if shadow == false {
                self.layer.masksToBounds = true
            }
        }
    }


    func addShadow(shadowColor: CGColor = UIColor.black.cgColor,
                   shadowOffset: CGSize = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 2.0),
                   shadowOpacity: Float = 0.4,
                   shadowRadius: CGFloat = 3.0) {
        layer.shadowColor = shadowColor
        layer.shadowOffset = shadowOffset
        layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
        layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
    }
}
```