# SwiftUI - NavigationView's navigation bar with rounded corner and shadow

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swiftui, ios-navigationview

I am using SwiftUI for my iOS (13+) application. The requirement is to have the bottom of the SwiftUI NavigationView's navigation bar rounded and shadowed. Like this:

[Navigation Bar with rounded bottom and shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhecW.png)

There is a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55417060/navigation-bar-with-shadow-corner-radius) regarding this subject, but the solution is for UIKit (not SwiftUI). I don't seems to be able to extend, modify, or replace the View (or UIView) used by SwiftUI's NavigationView. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show your own try and refer this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and then someone probably could help you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the appearance of NavigationBar using SwiftUI locally in Views. You can modify the Navigation bar using `UINavigationBar.appearance()`, but that will be applied to all the Navigation Bars in your app globally. The alternative would be to use `UIViewRepresentable` instead of View.

The latter has been demonstrated in the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505528/swiftui-update-navigation-bar-title-color)